# Window:willPositionSheet is not called when in full screen (10.8)?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm building a Mac application (not document based) that should run from 10.6 to 10.8. To simplify the editing of a special field, I use a sheet (with `beginSheet:modalForWindow...`) that is positioned immediately under the field, using the window delegate method `window:willPositionSheet:usingRect`. All is working well when the main window is a standard window, but when the window goes full screen (the new full screen in 10.7-10.8) the sheet is always positioned under the toolbar.
I found that the `willPositionSheet` is never called!
The funny thing is that other delegate methods continue to work... (this happens only with 10.7-10.8, as in 10.6 the full screen doesn't exist). 
Maybe I can work around this by presenting the sheet as a modal window when in full screen, but... is there trick to avoid this?
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a bug; report it at https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: This is still not getting called when the window is full screen in OS X 10.9, and 10.10.

Comment: Have you found some solution? It also reproduces in 10.12.